# I don't understand why my script is not iterating through all string.split elements?

Tags: python, string, loops

The objective of this python exercise is to build a function that turns text into pig latin, a simple text transformation that modifies each word by moving the first character to the end and appending "ay" to the end.

For example, `python` ends up as `ythonpay`.

I actually built this script, but I am confused as to why it is not iterating over all `text.split` elements? And why it is only modifying the last element?

```
def pig_latin(text):
      say = ""

    # Separate the text into words
      words = text.split()

      for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list

        new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        say =  "".join(new_word)

    # Turn the list back into a phrase
       return say

    print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) 
    # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"

    print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) 
    # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Comment: `say =  "".join(new_word)` - so you're setting `say` to `""` joined with `new_word` in every loop? In other words, just setting `say = new_word`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section here is why. You only have one new_word variable, so each time this loop runs, it overwrites the previous value. The only value that doesn't get overwritten is the last one, and you end up with a single string.

```
for word in words:
    new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
    say =  "".join(new_word)
```

Instead, make sure that each new word ends up in a list. The most intuitive way to do it, IMO, is through list comprehension. Below is how you would format it for this, but look up how to do them. Seriously, it's a couple minutes of your time and they'll be one of your best friends as you continue to learn. You can also do the same thing with dictionaries.

```
pig_latin_text = [word[1:] + word[0] + "ay" for word in words]
say =  " ".join(pig_latin)
```

Comment: Thank you LTheriault, i really should do hundreds exercises of python dictionary comprehension until i finally master it. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Of course, happy to help. The nice thing is that you don't have to do too many exercises to master. Once you have done a couple, maybe re-looked it up a couple times, they are very easy to remember. A lot of value for a little work. Good luck on your learning journey!

Answer (score 1):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    newword = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
    say = say + " " + newword
  return say
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over all the words, but you override the value in `say` in every iteration. Doing `say = "".join(new_word)` will not combine the new word with the existing value of `say`, but override it - the `join` function joins the arguments it receives, and in this case it only received `new_word`.

To fix it you should replace that line with:

```
say += " " + new_word
```

Comment: thank you for you help. but your suggestion gives me this output /ellohayowhayreaayouyay
rogrammingpayniayythonpaysiayunfay/ but i need seperated words

Comment: I edited the answer to put spaces between the words.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
    say =  say + " " + "".join(new_word) 
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return say
        
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer