# Why can't word.lstrip be assigned to function call?

Tags: python

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    word.lstrip(-1) += (word[0]+"ay")
    say.append(word)
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return say
        
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Getting a syntax error on word.lstrip.. I can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014737/i-dont-understand-why-my-script-is-not-iterating-through-all-string-split-eleme) I just need to know what I'm not understanding about .lstrip and maybe even for loops..

Comment: `word.lstrip(-1)` is not an `lvalue` so can't be used left of the `+=` will be your next error

Answer (score 1):

`"   hi   ".lstrip(-1)` returns this error on my machine: `TypeError: lstrip arg must be None or str`.

`"   hi   ".lstrip()` returns `'hi   '`.

`"tttthi   ".lstrip("t")` returns `'hi   '`.

The `lstrip()` method only accepts a string argument or no argument at all.  You're supplying an integer argument and that's why it's erroring out.